# Как улучшить это регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как улучшить это регулярное выражение `(.+?)\=(.*?)\&`

Например сейчас оно делает так,

Строка `TEST3=TEST5&TEST=44`

Выдаст

```
[1] = TEST3
[2] = TEST5
```

Строка `TEST3=TEST5`

Он должен

```
[1] = TEST3
[2] = TEST5
```

но он выдаст ничего потамучто у меня в регулярке стоит проверка символа &
Как сделать такое регулярное выражение?

Comment: Вам не нужно регулярное выражение. Без привязки к языку программирования: разбиваете строку на массив по `&`, затем каждый элемент массива разбиваете по `=`. Но вероятно в вашем языке программирования есть функция для преобразования строки параметров в массив переменных.

Comment: Еще как нужно) не вариант ваши действия.

Comment: укажите язык программирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ищите в конце не только `&`, но еще и конец строки - `$`

```
(.+?)\=(.*?)(\&|$)
```

Comment: Тоже рабочий вариант, но он выкидывает еще [3]=&, вариант выше все отлично выполняет

Comment: @ДенисКотляров это нормально, что выдается 3-я группа. Если вам нужны гарантированно два совпадения - используйте именованные группы. обращение по индексу - слишком хрупкое.

Comment: А, хотя, спасибо, это даже лучше, я могу знать был ли & в строке, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Раз вам все-таки нужно регулярное выражение используйте этот вариант:

```
(.+?)\=([^\&]*)
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/oX8tK8/1

P.S. `*` во второй группе вероятно следует заменить на `+`, чтобы регулярное выражение не реагировало на такую строку `TEST3=`

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, правда, что ваша, что моя регулярка сработает и на `TEST3==TEST5&`

Comment: Отлично, все работает